# Межстраничное объявление в LibGdx

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx

Просто как межстраничник делать знаю. Как делать баннер в LibGdx тоже полно всего. А межстраничники как то относительно недавно появились, информации по ним мало, да и LibGdx, Android Stidio и Gradle быстро развиваются, даже информация по баннерам не работает в новых версиях. 
Работал кто нибудь с межстраничными объявлениями AdMob в LibGdx?

Comment: В этом видео хорошо объясняют https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7pXcEIl-G8